# Toggle between two div tags using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm facing problem with toggle using JQuery between two divs. I don't have much knowledge with JQuery.
I want to display div1(create) when clicking a create and should hide div2(insert). In the same way when I click insert it should display div2(insert) and hide div1(create). Can some one please help me with this?

This is the code for anchor tags
     #Start of div tag1

```
 <div id="first"><h2 align="center">Array Operations</h2><br><br><br>
                   <a href="create">Creation</a><br>
                   <a href="insert">Insertion</a><br>
 </div> #End of div1
```

This the code for div tags

```
<div id="second"> #Start of div tag2
 <div class="create">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#cpp">C++</a></li>
  </ul>
 <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="cpp" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>#Creating an array in C++</h3>
    <p>#include &lt; iostream &gt; <br>
    using namespace std;<br>
    int a [10]</p>
    </div>
 </div>
</div> #End of create div
<div class="insert">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
     <li class="active"><a href="#cpp">C++</a></li>
   </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="cpp" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>#Inserting an array in C++</h3>
      <p>#include &lt; iostream &gt; <br>
      using namespace std;<br>
      int a [10]</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> #End of insert div
</div> #End of div tag2
```

This is css for first div tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#myTab a").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).tab('show');
  });
});
</script>   
<style>
#first {
width: 25%;
float: left;
height: 300px;
border-left: 1px solid gray;
border-top: 1px solid gray;
border-right: 1px solid gray;
}
#second {
width: 70%;
float: left;
height: 300px;
border-top: 1px solid gray;
}
</style>
```

This is the jquery

```
$('.insert').hide();
 $('.create, .insert').on('click',
  function() {
  $('.create, .insert').toggle()
 }
);
```

Comment: Where's your CSS and what js/jquery have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I added a class for all of the page sections called `.panel` that hides the panels by default (`display: none;`), and gave the first panel a class of `.active` which will show a panel. Then when you click on one of the links at the top, use the `href` attribute to target the class of the panel, remove `.active` from any panel you didn't click on, and add `.active` to the one you clicked on.

```js
var $panels = $('.panel'),
    $links = $('#first a');
$links.on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $target = $('.' + $(this).attr('href'));
  $panels.not($target).removeClass('active');
  $target.addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.panel {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
  <h2 align="center">Array Operations</h2><br><br><br>
  <a href="create">Creation</a><br>
  <a href="insert">Insertion</a><br>
</div>
<div class="create panel active">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#cpp">C++</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="cpp" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>#Creating an array in C++</h3>
      <p>#include &lt; iostream &gt; <br> using namespace std;<br> int a [10]</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="insert panel">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#cpp">C++</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="cpp" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>#Inserting an array in C++</h3>
      <p>#include &lt; iostream &gt; <br> using namespace std;<br> int a [10]</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working but when I'm trying to add one more button                    <li class="active"><a href="#cpp">C++</a></li>                                   <li><a href="#java">java</a></li>                                                                           it is not allowing my previous functionality which displays different information for different buttons in the tab                                                         $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#myTab a").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).tab('show');
    });
}); Please help me with this!

Comment: @toni that code is incomplete. Where are you initializing `$.tabs()`? And `$.tab()` is wrong, assuming this is jqueryUI. It's `$.tabs()`

Comment: Can you help me with jquery for that? I want two buttons(c++ and java) in <li> tag. When I C++ then it should display information of #cpp and when i click on java then it should display information of #java.

Comment: @toni If you haven't integrated jqueryUI tabs, that's a separate question from the one in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code using simple jQuery syntax to show/hide the divs you mentioned. You can test the code here --> https://jsfiddle.net/Lp8m2mry/

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){    <!--jQuery function that fires when document is ready-->
            $('a#create').click(function() {    <!--jQuery function creates a click even listener on the a tag with id of create-->
                $('div.create').show();    <!--jQuery function that applies the default display property to element-->
                $('div.insert').hide();    <!--jQuery function that applies style of display:none to element -->
            });
            $('a#insert').click(function() {
                $('div.insert').show();
                $('div.create').hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        div.create {
            display: none;
        }

        div.insert {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="first"><h2 align="center">Array Operations</h2><br><br><br>
        <a id="create" href="#">Creation</a><br>
        <a id="insert" href="#">Insertion</a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="create">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li class="active"><a href="#cpp">C++</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="cpp" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <h3>#Creating an array in C++</h3>
                <p>#include &lt; iostream &gt; <br>
                using namespace std;<br>
                int a [10]</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <!--#End of create div-->
    <div class="insert">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li class="active"><a href="#cpp">C++</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="cpp" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <h3>#Inserting an array in C++</h3>
                <p>#include &lt; iostream &gt; <br>
                using namespace std;<br>
                int a [10]</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--#End of insert div-->
</body>
```

Comment: Great. Glad to hear it. Please up vote the answer if you don't mind. Take care!